# Enforcing Cdate in VBA Excel when retrieving Meta Data

Tags: excel, vba, metadata

I have this code which is successfully returning the 0-5 items of meta data. However, the dates are returning as mixed US and UK formats... I need to enforce Cdate or something similar to get the dates to all read as UK date. (DD/MM/YY) I have usually used Cdate for other things, but unsure how to get it to work....

Code:

```
 Dim sFile As Object, obja

'Create Shell Object & NameSpace
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("FILEPATH")
ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents

'Loop thru each File/Folder inside Root Directory
iRow = 1

For Each sFile In oDir.Items
    iRow = iRow + 1
    
    'Loop thru Each Property
    For i = 0 To 5
        
        'Get File Property Name & Value
        obja = oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, i)
        If obja <> "" Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
            'Enter File Property to Sheet
            ActiveSheet.Range("A" & iRow) = oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir, i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow) = obja
        End If
    Next
Next

MsgBox "Process Completed"

 End Sub
```

Comment: There's no CDate in your code?  Code you explain what you are trying to do or what your question is?  Maybe some examples would help.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I refer to Cdate as something I have used in the past. I am unsure what to use to force the above code to save the dates from meta data into the Spreadsheet

Comment: It's not clear what the problem here is.  I think that if you could provide some example data and what results you want/need from it, that might make it clearer.

Comment: The above code is mixing up US and UK date formats. I want just UK date formats

Comment: Again, if you could provide an example of the different input data, what output you are currently getting and what you want as output, that would help a lot.  That's just a table of say 3-5 input values with three columns ( input, current output, expected output).  Don't worry about formatting the table, just give us the data and we can format it into your post.

Comment: If you don't want use the value as a date (ie a double) then format the column as text with `ActiveSheet.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: I would like it to be a date, but if the date is 05/11/21 (DDMMYY), sometimes it will revert to 11/05/21 (MMDDYY). I would like it all to read DDMMYY without it being mixed up using the above code

Comment: @scott what is the format of column B is it dd/mm/yy or general ?

Comment: The formats I have changed on several occasions to enforce the dates in the correct format, but it has made no difference as yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the date properties split the string into day,month,year,hour,minute and then recreate the date with `DateSerial()` and `TimeSerial()`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub files()

    Dim sFile As Object, obja, oShell, oDir
    Dim iRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sValue, sName As String
    Dim arDT, arDMY, arHMS, dt As Date
    
    'Create Shell Object & NameSpace
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("C:\temp\so\data")
    ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents
    
    'Loop thru each File/Folder inside Root Directory
    iRow = 1
    
    For Each sFile In oDir.Items
        iRow = iRow + 1
        
        'Loop thru Each Property
        For i = 0 To 5
             sName = oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir, i)
            sValue = oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, i)
            
            If sValue <> "" Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
                Range("A" & iRow) = sName
                If sName Like "Date*" Then
                    ' sValue is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm
                    arDT = Split(sValue, " ")
                    arDMY = Split(arDT(0), "/")
                    arHMS = Split(arDT(1), ":")
                    
                    dt = DateSerial(arDMY(2), arDMY(1), arDMY(0)) _
                           + TimeSerial(arHMS(0), arHMS(1), 0)
                    Range("B" & iRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm"
                    Range("B" & iRow) = dt
                Else
                    Range("B" & iRow) = sValue
                End If
               
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Recommend this date enforcing... Sorry if I caused confusion over saying about cDate. I thought it was ok, but maybe a crass way of explaining the problem.